# How to set window size on runtime?

Tags: java, resize, window, runtime, javafx

I'm developing a JavaFX FXML application. I need to resize the window from the controller class at runtime.

I found out that its possible to do this from the application class by setting maxHeight and maxWidth properties of the stage. But how to do it from the controller class while the application is running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a button in the controller class and set on action of it like

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        // OR, if you define btn as @FXML private Button btn.
        Stage stage = (Stage) btn.getScene().getWindow();
        // these two of them return the same stage
        stage.setWidth(new_val);
        stage.setHeight(new_val);
    }
});
```

where stage is your primary (main) stage.

Comment: Ah yes. But the code you mentioned should be in the application class(the .java file with start and main functions) right? But the problem is I need to set the size from the controller class. Is it possible?

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. You just made my day better :)